debian machine drops connection time by time
I've a Debian 11 machine with some audio streaming on it. The last days the connection drops and the dj's and listeners are dropping with a connection fault. When i monitor the network i see in netstat the complete connection is dropping. i contacted my isp and they see no problems on the connection on their machines. Can it be a ddos attack or something?
I checked the log files but i can't find anything to resuffer the issue.

The drops are on 13:24 and 15:08
I've reinstalled the debian machine but without luck.
Does anyone know anything about this and might know what could be going on here?
Only the streaming and CSF firewall and Prometheus for network monitoring is running on the server.
Update 20-06:
Today problems again, connection drops over longer time see screen.
screen
Now i see something in log file but i dont know if this occur with the connection issue:
Jun 20 15:21:06 server1 snapd[453]: autorefresh.go:643: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change: too many requests
Jun 20 15:21:06 server1 snapd[453]: stateengine.go:149: state ensure error: too many requests

You have to figure out what happens. That likely includes going to town with a packet capture, and figure out if there's an RST somewhere, or similar.

Packets drop also.. see picture https://ibb.co/z6TMLnG

The picture doesn't help in any way. All it shows is that for some reason traffic drops. Why? You have to look in your logs (both client and server), and if that doesn't provide enough hints, a packet capture is generally the next step.
